# Tem como fazer um script QUE a cada mês, dia e horário na imagem apareça automático uma saudação de "TEXTO"e que após o horário finalize

Tags: javascript, html

SOU INICIANTE !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<div class="container"><img align="left" height="230" Width="190"src="https://a.imagem.app/boADmE.png"/><center><a href='go:SBT$' target='Player'><p>04 Fev 17h30 Ceará <br>x<br> Sampaio Corrêa</p></center></div>
<div class="container"><img align="left" height="230" Width="190"src="https://a.imagem.app/boADmE.png"/><center><a href='go:SBT$' target='Player'><p>04 Fev 17h30 Náutico <br>x<br> CRB</p></center></div>

<div class="container"><img align="left" height="230" Width="190"src="https://a.imagem.app/boADmE.png"/><center><a href='go:espn$' target='Player'><p>04  Fev 18h00 ABC <br>x<br> FortalezaCopa do Nordeste</p></center></div>

</center>
<style>
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.container p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 22px;
  Width:140px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<body bgcolor="rgb(0,0,0)">
<body bgcolor="black">


</center>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Importante [editar sua postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/576393/70) conforme orientações já dadas. Ao editar, a pergunta é reavaliada pela comunidade. Para evitar duplicação de orientações o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas está disponível na postagem original (observe a opção de "restaurar" a postagem, se necessário).